# rocket application embed migrations not applying

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I'm trying to embed Diesel migrations into my rocket applications but whenever I attempt to select the tables they don't exist. The "Migrations successfully completed" message gets printed and rocket starts normally but the migrations don't seem to be applying, I'm really not sure what's happening here.

I tested the PgPool connection when I manually did migrations and it works fine.

my migrations directory:

- 00000000000000_diesel_initial_setup

  - down.sql
  - up.sql
- 2022-11-13-225713_users

  - down.sql
  - up.sql

my dependencies:

- diesel = { version = "2.0.2", features = ["postgres", "nightly-error-messages", "r2d2"] }
- diesel_migrations = "2.0.0"
- rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"] }

```
pub const MIGRATIONS: EmbeddedMigrations = embed_migrations!("migrations");

fn run_migrations(connection: &mut impl MigrationHarness<diesel::pg::Pg>) {
    match connection.run_pending_migrations(MIGRATIONS) {
        Ok(_) => {
            println!("Migrations successfully completed");
        },
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("error running pending migrations {}", e)
        },
    };
}

async fn run_rocket_migrations(rocket: Rocket<Build>) -> Rocket<Build> {
    let mut pool = rocket.state::<PgPool>().expect("managed database").get().unwrap();
    run_migrations(&mut pool);
    
    rocket
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .manage(establish_connection())
        .attach(AdHoc::on_ignite("run migrations", run_rocket_migrations))
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing important information. You might want to add information about the versions of your dependencies and the content of your migrations directory. [mre]

Comment: @weiznich I updated it

Comment: what does the `diesel_migrations` table contain? And did you verify that your migrations are actually working by using the diesel cli first?